# css: make inner container height 100% with top and bottom margin

Tags: html, css

I have strange case:

I try to make an inner container to fill parent (height with 100% height), but as result I get overflowed content in bottom:

[image]

But it must be so (100% except margin top and bottom):

[image]

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <aside class="full-nav" action-bar>
        </aside>
      <section class="wrapper">
            <header>
            </header>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="innner-wrapper">
            <div class="main-partial">
                <div class="content-wrapper">Content</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and plunker (CSSit there):

http://plnkr.co/edit/ku7ZXK6uezfZ86cMFhds?p=preview

(when I set absolute position I get strange width...)

Comment: I do not really understand what the issue you have here is? Could you remove a lot of the CSS from your example so we can help?

Comment: It isn't a strange case — `.content` have `height: 100%` and `<header>` have `height: 40px`, also you can't set height considering `margin`, only hardcode it with `calc()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the height of the `.content-wrapper` and adjust it.

```
.content-wrapper {
   height: calc(100% - 70px);
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Adjusted Wrapper]

```css
/* Styles go here */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-width: 1024px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.pull-right {
  float: left;
}
.pull-left {
  float: left;
}
.main-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
aside {
  width: 48px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #dedede;
  position: absolute;
}
aside.full-nav {
  width: 168px;
}
section.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 168px;
  background: #eeeeee;
}
section.wrapper.full-size {
  padding-left: 48px;
}
aside ul.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}
aside nav ul li {
  height: 34px;
}
aside nav ul li:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
aside.full-nav nav ul li.company-name {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #717cba;
  position: relative;
}
aside.full-nav nav ul li.company-name span {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
aside nav ul li a {
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 1;
  max-height: 34px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 5px 0 0 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
aside.full-nav nav ul li a.first {
  margin: 20px 0 0 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
aside nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
aside nav ul li.company-name .nav-company-overflow {
  display: none;
}
aside nav ul li.company-name .nav-company-logo {
  display: none;
}
aside.full-nav nav ul li.company-name a {
  height: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 10px 0 0 12px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
}
aside.full-nav nav ul li.company-name .nav-company-overflow {
  width: 168px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(78, 91, 169, 0.8);
  z-index: 15;
  display: block;
}
aside.full-nav nav ul li.company-name .nav-company-logo {
  width: 168px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
}
aside nav ul li a em {
  line-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 18px 0 0;
}
aside nav ul li a span {
  width: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 110px;
}
aside nav ul li a.profile em {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url(../images/png/profile_spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -10px -676px;
  margin: 6px 8px 0 0;
}
aside.full-nav nav ul li a.profile em {
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}
aside nav ul li a.contacts em {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(../images/png/profile_spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -10px -224px;
}
aside nav ul li a.events em {
  width: 20px;
  height: 22px;
  background: url(../images/png/profile_spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -10px -268px;
}
aside nav ul li a.policy em {
  width: 20px;
  height: 23px;
  background: url(../images/png/profile_spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -10px -310px;
}
aside nav ul li a.admins em {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url(../images/png/profile_spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -10px -676px;
}
aside.full-nav nav ul li a span {
  display: inline-block;
}
aside nav ul li a span {
  display: none;
}
aside .hide-sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  background: #455095;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
#hide-sidebar-btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #394485;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
#hide-sidebar-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
aside .collapse-btn-icon {
  width: 8px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(../images/png/profile_spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -10px -353px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
aside.full-nav .collapse-btn-icon {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.innner-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 12px 0 12px;
}
.main-partial {
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  height: 40px;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
header .buttons-header-area {
  float: right;
}
header .company-header-avatar {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  border-radius: 28px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  margin: 7px 0 0 5px;
  float: left;
}
header .info {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
header .info em {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url(../images/png/profile_spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -10px -53px;
}
header .dropdown-toggle {
  width: 170px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #444444;
}
header .btn-group {
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
header .btn-group.open {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
header .open > .dropdown-menu {
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-color: #d9d9d9;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}
header .dropdown-toggle:hover {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
header .profile-name {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
header .caret {
  height: 40px;
  border-top: 6px solid #bfbfbf;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 12px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content-wrapper {
  background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
  width: 100%;
}
.content-row.company {
  height: 300px;
}
.content-row-wrapper {
  margin: 0 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-wrapper">
    <aside class="full-nav" action-bar>
    </aside>
    <section class="wrapper">
      <header>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="innner-wrapper">
          <div class="main-partial">
            <div class="content-wrapper">Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: still footer there: http://prntscr.com/7p5tye

http://plnkr.co/edit/ku7ZXK6uezfZ86cMFhds?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are assigning 100% height to the container and this one is getting the relative window height. The problem is the header at the top of the page does not let this to work. Maybe you have to calculate with javascript or something to apply the correct height to that container.